# How to introduce a click event in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this already works for onchange just for the input field only btu
i'm trying to make the ajax work when the search button is clicked
the url calls the php side which is in perfect condition

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function  bn(val)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'salprefix.php',
                data: {
                    submitname:val
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    document.getElementById("submitname").innerHTML=response;
                }
            });


        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method='post' action='#'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>                    
                    <label for='name'>Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' id='staffname' name='staffname' onchange='bn(this.value);'>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'>
                    <input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='Search'>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id = 'submitname'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: where is your search button?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/2672355/1650891](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2672355/1650891)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to don't add event in HTML for best practice

```
<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Search">

<script>
    //Javascript way
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('submit!');
    })

    //jQuery way
    $('#submit').on('click', function() {
        alert('submit!');
    });
<script>
```

Comment: how do i get to pass the values from the input

Comment: instead of the `alert`, use `bn($('#staffname').val())`

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type='button' id='submit' name='submit' value='Search' onclick="bn(staffname.value)">
```

try this if you want to call the function with inline

But I suggest you should separate html and js script code like D. Schreier suggested :)

Comment: most welcome :)

Comment: This works but you should prefer D. Scheier answer, it is more elegant and uses jQuery.